# NSOutlineView (or NSTableView) with custom NSTableCellView doesn't create connections to outlets

Tags: xcode, interface-builder, nstableview, iboutlet, nsoutlineview

A .nib file contains `NSOutlineView` (1-column, view-based). Column has identifier "UserCell"; it also has one cell which has two `NSTextField`'s and bunch of buttons; this cell also has identifier "UserCell". Class for this cell is set in IB to be a custom class derived from `NSTableCellView` class. I option-dragged both `NSTextField`'s to the custom code (see picture attached) to create IBOutlets.

[image: NSTexFiled's IBOutlets]

In delegate's method `-outlineView:viewForTableColumn:item:` I load cell using `-makeViewWithIdentifier:owner:` and it loads fine - I get my custom cell view object. However, both text fields are `nil`'s.

How one should fix it? The same story with `NSTableView`.

Comment: Is anything logged to the console when the cell view is loaded? If you select the cell view in IB and look at the Connections inspector, does it show the outlets as connected?

Comment: When I select a text field, it shows that it is referened in "Referencing Outlets". However I noticed strange behavior - when I right-clik on the cell, it does not show any outlets at all and shows that it has no outlet called `textField`, which is an outlet from base class `NSTableCellView`. Also, when I changed cell view class to my custom class, it did not auto-complete as usually IB does. Finally, those text fields that are connected to `NSTableCellView`'s `textField` attribute work properly.